# Multi index query with restriction on a given type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a problem on elastic,

I make some query string on multiple index, multiple type, but in some case I want to restrict the results on a specific type.

More precisely : 
My request return a list of people and a list of products in the case I'm an admin, however if I'm a simple user the request must return the list of products but only my information and not the list of people.

Thank you

Comment: How about adding a `term` query on the `_type` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look indices :

```
     "must": {
        "indices": {
           "indices": [
              "my_index"
           ],
           "query": {
              "term": {
                 "user.id": "123"
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, You are a chief :)

Answer (score 0):

In 5.1 you should use Type Query:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-type-query.html

Before it used to be Type Filter:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-type-filter.html

Comment: In fact this could work but I've several indexes and if Ido that don't I restrain my search to that type?

Comment: In fact you have asked - I want to restrict the results on a specific type. Do you spawn single type over several indices?